# Enter Key not working in JFileChoose in Java 7

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am facing an issue while working on JFileChooser for Java 7.When I click enter key(Directory Browse) on a directory, I see no actions  and  key press is ignored.
Below is my code implementation.

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Popup");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
    fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
    frame.add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println(actionEvent.getSource());
        JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent.getSource();
        String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
          File selectedFile = theFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
          System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
          System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
        } else if (command.equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
          System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
        }
      }
    };
    fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Any Help is Really Appreciated !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);` line, the ENTER button will work.

Plus.... your user will be able to use the normal buttons they expect to see in a dialog!

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply.I removed the line  fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false); But No Luck :(